# Loop to assign a value if an observation in one column is equal to other column's name in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a vector and a data set that are similar to:

```
id_vector <- as.character(c("n01", "n02", "n03"))
df_1 <- data.frame("id" = c("n01", "n02", "n02", "n03"), "n01" = NA, "n02" = NA,  "n03" = NA)
df_1$id <- as.character(df_1$id)
```

And I want the data set to be:

```
df_2 <- data.frame("id" = c("n01", "n02", "n02", "n03"), "n01" = c(1, NA, NA, NA), "n02" = c(NA, 1, 1, NA),  "n03" = c(NA, NA, NA, 1))
```

The solution should be simple, something like:

```
for (i in id_vector){
  df_1[i][df_1$id == i] <- 1
}
```

However, I can't use two []s. The error is:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df_1$id == i, value = 1) : 
duplicate subscripts for columns
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can subset the vector with `[[`.  `df_1[1]` is still a `data.frame` with a single column

```
for (i in id_vector){
   df_1[[i]][df_1$id == i] <- 1
  }

identical(df_1, df_2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row/column matrix to change value to 1.

```
df_1[id_vector][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df_1)), match(df_1$id, id_vector))] <- 1
df_1

#   id n01 n02 n03
#1 n01   1  NA  NA
#2 n02  NA   1  NA
#3 n02  NA   1  NA
#4 n03  NA  NA   1
```

---

To explain he above, we use `match` to get column numbers to replace whereas `seq_len(nrow(df_1))` gives us a sequence `1:nrow(df)`. Using `cbind` we turn them to matrix.

```
cbind(seq_len(nrow(df_1)), match(df_1$id, id_vector))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    3    2
#[4,]    4    3
```

Now we subset only `id_vector` columns, subset the dataframe based on the above matrix and assign the values to 1.